# How to digitally "amplitude modulate" an LED

Tags: led, pwm, optoelectronics

I am wanting to do some open-air LED communication experiments.

I have a receiver that detects Amplitude Modulated light signals, and then converts that into sound.

Currently, I hook up a series transformer with the LED with an audio source on the primary.

I have heard that if I Pulse Width Modulate the LED, the detector will perceive that as AM.

What type of circuit could I use to convert a sound signal into fast PWM for the LED?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest route would be to use a linear technology PWM chip - I'm thinking of the LTC6992: -

[image]

You choose a resistor value that sets the PWM frequency and your control input (from your audio) would feed the MOD input. Make sure your audio is conditioned to be centred at 0.5volts thus allowing the signal to produce 50% mark-space ratio when audio level is quiet.

Also make sure that you don't go into clipping situations when the audio level hits 1Vp-p - you might want to use a pot to ensure you can't overdrive the chip and also double check what the absolute maximum ratings are in case you do.

The output is obviously a square wave (mark-space modulated) at between 0V and 3.3V - this should be fed thru an appropriate circuit to drive the LED. I can't give details because I don't know your LED power requirements.

Comment: Thanks! I will be using a 10 watt LED with some driver circuit like this http://cdn.instructables.com/FHY/YUTR/RCQEWP86JFY/FHYYUTRRCQEWP86JFY.MEDIUM.jpg

Comment: Yeah that's a tried and tested type of circuit when you need to keep your current limiter resistor at a low value. Should work fine. Experiment with higher values of R1 to begin with just in case - maybe 10k but should work down to 1k.